# Star rating system save value on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a star rating system, i have this code and i want to make some changes on it, after the user clicks on the stars it shows an alert with how many stars and it resets the colors, what i want is the color filling to stay after the user clicks on it, and replace the alert with a div under the stars, here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
    $("div.star-rating > s, div.star-rating-rtl > s").on("click", function(e) {
        var numStars = $(e.target).parentsUntil("div").length+1;
        alert(numStars + (numStars == 1 ? " star" : " stars!"));
    });
});
```

```css
.star-rating s:hover {
    color: red;
}
.star-rating-rtl s:hover {
    color: red;
}

.star-rating s,
.star-rating-rtl s {
    color: black;
    font-size: 50px;
    cursor: default;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
}
.star-rating {
    padding: 2px;
}
.star-rating-rtl {
    background: #555;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #444;
}
.star-rating-rtl s {
    color: yellow;
}
.star-rating s:hover:before, .star-rating s.rated:before {
    content: "\2605";
}
.star-rating s:before {
    content: "\2606";
}
.star-rating-rtl s:hover:after, .star-rating-rtl s.rated:after{
    content: "\2605";
}
.star-rating-rtl s:after {
    content: "\2606";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="star-rating"><s><s><s><s><s></s></s></s></s></s></div>
<div class="star-rating-rtl"><s><s><s><s><s></s></s></s></s></s></div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See for the `.active` class added in CSS to find the changes there.

See code and comments in JS

```js
$(function() {
    $("div.star-rating > s, div.star-rating-rtl > s").on("click", function(e) {
    
    // remove all active classes first, needed if user clicks multiple times
    $(this).closest('div').find('.active').removeClass('active');

    $(e.target).parentsUntil("div").addClass('active'); // all elements up from the clicked one excluding self
    $(e.target).addClass('active');  // the element user has clicked on


        var numStars = $(e.target).parentsUntil("div").length+1;
        $('.show-result').text(numStars + (numStars == 1 ? " star" : " stars!"));
    });
});
```

```css
.show-result {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: green;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.star-rating s:hover,
.star-rating s.active {
    color: red;
}
.star-rating-rtl s:hover,
.star-rating-rtl s.active {
    color: red;
}

.star-rating s,
.star-rating-rtl s {
    color: black;
    font-size: 50px;
    cursor: default;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
}
.star-rating {
    padding: 2px;
}
.star-rating-rtl {
    background: #555;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #444;
}
.star-rating-rtl s {
    color: yellow;
}
.star-rating s:hover:before,
.star-rating s.rated:before,
.star-rating s.active:before {
    content: "\2605";
}
.star-rating s:before {
    content: "\2606";
}
.star-rating-rtl s:hover:after,
.star-rating-rtl s.rated:after,
.star-rating-rtl s.active:after {
    content: "\2605";
}

.star-rating-rtl s:after {
    content: "\2606";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="star-rating"><s><s><s><s><s></s></s></s></s></s></div>
<div class="star-rating-rtl"><s><s><s><s><s></s></s></s></s></s></div>

<div class="show-result">No stars selected yet.</div>
```

Comment: I made a small edit in the question, can you please take a look

Comment: @jessica you mean you don't want the alert but to show the number in some `<div>`?

Comment: can you help me out in something please?

Answer (score 2):

Here are two options:

When the user clicks, set a class on the parent container == to the star rating, like `rated-3`. Then, use CSS' `first-child` and sibling selectors to active the first star and N more stores.

When the user clicks, use JS to set `class="active"` on all stars up to and including the clicked star.

For either scenario, replicate your hover CSS to apply to `.active` or `:first-child, :first-child+s,...`. elements.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it. 
Add another div under your star divs and give it an id lets say id=selectedStars

in your js code replace alert line with this one

document.getElementById('selectedStars').innerHTML=numStars;

here you go , this will give you selected stars count in the last div

Answer (score 1):

Here's the option by using the class `rated` that you have in your CSS.

```
//remove ratings
$("s").removeClass("rated");
//adds the rated class
$(e.target).parents("s").addClass('rated');
$(e.target).closest("s").addClass('rated');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
    $("div.star-rating > s, div.star-rating-rtl > s").on("click", function(e) {
    
    // remove all active classes first, needed if user clicks multiple times
    $(this).closest('div').find('.active').removeClass('active');

    $(e.target).parentsUntil("div").addClass('active'); // all elements up from the clicked one excluding self
    $(e.target).addClass('active');  // the element user has clicked on


        var numStars = $(e.target).parentsUntil("div").length+1;
        $('.show-result').text(numStars + (numStars == 1 ? " star" : " stars!"));
    });
});
```

```css
.show-result {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: green;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.star-rating s:hover,
.star-rating s.active {
    color: red;
}
.star-rating-rtl s:hover,
.star-rating-rtl s.active {
    color: red;
}

.star-rating s,
.star-rating-rtl s {
    color: black;
    font-size: 50px;
    cursor: default;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
}
.star-rating {
    padding: 2px;
}
.star-rating-rtl {
    background: #555;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #444;
}
.star-rating-rtl s {
    color: yellow;
}
.star-rating s:hover:before,
.star-rating s.rated:before,
.star-rating s.active:before {
    content: "\2605";
}
.star-rating s:before {
    content: "\2606";
}
.star-rating-rtl s:hover:after,
.star-rating-rtl s.rated:after,
.star-rating-rtl s.active:after {
    content: "\2605";
}

.star-rating-rtl s:after {
    content: "\2606";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="star-rating"><s><s><s><s><s></s></s></s></s></s></div>
<div class="star-rating-rtl"><s><s><s><s><s></s></s></s></s></s></div>

<div class="show-result">No stars selected yet.</div>
```